# How to use custom templates in Swagger

Tags: java, mustache, swagger

I have this JavaJaxRs dictionary with my templates:

```
/templates/JavaJaxRs
```

I edited some of them. And want to use them for my API generation (Code was inspired from this approach from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/plugin/CodeGenMojo.java):

```
    System.out.println("Generating API for: " + location);
    DefaultGenerator generator = new DefaultGenerator();
    Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read(location);
    CodegenConfig config = CodegenConfigLoader.forName(this.language);
    config.setOutputDir(new File(this.apiGeneratedSrcPath).getPath());

    if (null != templateDirectory) {
        config.additionalProperties().put(TEMPLATE_DIR_PARAM, templateDirectory);
    }
    if (null != modelPackage) {
        config.additionalProperties().put(MODEL_PACKAGE_PARAM, modelPackage);
    }
    if (null != apiPackage) {
        config.additionalProperties().put(API_PACKAGE_PARAM, apiPackage);
    }
    if (null != invokerPackage) {
        config.additionalProperties().put(INVOKER_PACKAGE_PARAM, invokerPackage);
    }

    if (configOptions != null) {
        for (CliOption langCliOption : config.cliOptions()) {
            if (configOptions.containsKey(langCliOption.getOpt())) {
                config.additionalProperties().put(langCliOption.getOpt(),
                        configOptions.get(langCliOption.getOpt()));
            }
        }
    }

    if (null != configurationFile) {
        Config genConfig = ConfigParser.read(configurationFile);
        if (null != genConfig) {
            for (CliOption langCliOption : config.cliOptions()) {
                if (genConfig.hasOption(langCliOption.getOpt())) {
                    config.additionalProperties().put(langCliOption.getOpt(), genConfig.getOption(langCliOption.getOpt()));
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read configuration file");
        }
    }

    ClientOptInput input = new ClientOptInput().opts(new ClientOpts()).swagger(swagger);
    input.setConfig(config);

    generator.opts(input).generate();
```

Somehow i always get the code generated with the standard template file.

UPDATE:

When i remember correctly i had a conditional bug on:

```
if(null != templateDirectory)
    config.additionalProperties().put(TEMPLATE_DIR_PARAM, templateDirectory);
```

or somewhere else but with the right condition, code was working as intended.

I let the question stay here, maybe it will help some other users.

Comment: I want to use custom templates with Nswagger in ASP .Net Core. I have tried many things but it does not work. You have done this in java but let me know please if you have any idea about this in .Net Core.
I'm new for Nswagger

Comment: I have no experience with Nswagger, so i can't help you there. But the swagger docs have been updated and if these don't help you could ask a new question on SO about this topic (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the help options for the code generator like such:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar help generate
```

Which should tell you that you can override the template location with the `-t` parameter:

```
java -java swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l {language} -t path/to/templates
```

Comment: i think i am doing this with `config.additionalProperties().put(TEMPLATE_DIR_PARAM, templateDirectory);`

Comment: I had a wrong condition, in my code so the line to adapt the params wsa not executed. It's been working good for awhile now.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the above `ava -java swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l {language} -t path/to/templates`,

I've managed to make it work with current being-worked-on-release (2.2.0).
With 2.1.6 (current GA) it does not work.

I have posted the following on swagger-codegen at GitHub:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3188

Did not get any attention though...

Comment: Just came by here to mention that 2.2.0 has been released.