# autogenerate pojos with builder methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, lombok

Presently I am using swagger codegen tool to convert a RAML definition into swagger format and generating java client from this format. This gives me POJOs for all the data types mentioned in the RAML. Every time I change some data field in the RAML types, I have to regenerate the POJOs and all the code implementation in service layers has to be rewritten. It is becoming very cumbersome to repeatedly do the same things.

I am thinking if only these POJOs were generated with builder pattern, like,

mydataobject.builder.addfield1(10).addfield2(2);
it will greatly help me keep the code in service layer untouched.

Is there a way to auto-generate pojos that have builder methods in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for that.

```
@lombok.Builder// Builder companion class, and static method
@lombok.Value // Getters, setters, and contructors
class Pojo {
    String value;
    Number number;
}
```

Which gives you this code:

```
final Pojo pojo = Pojo.builder()
    .value("foo")
    .number(100)
    .build();
```

You have to proceed your generated code in order to add this annotations, see [Add lombok (or any) annotation to swagger generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467505/add-lombok-or-any-annotation-to-swagger-generated-class) for discussion of that.

Comment: Hi @andreoss thanks for the answer, I still have to add Lombok '@Builder' annotation to all the autogenerated classes manually. Is there way to do it quickly, programmatically?

Comment: @Sriman At this point, yes, there is feature request for this in `swagger-codegen`. I believe you can process this code with maven `antrun` task  placed some between `swagger` and `compile` goals.

Comment: @Sriman Take a look into this also, you might be able to pass custome templates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436487/howto-use-custom-templates-in-swagger